# can not update from 5.1 to 6.0

Tags: updates, uefi

i have a medion akoya e3223, i am running elementary os 5.1 on it
just bought elementary os 6.0 but i can not install it, because  i can not enter boot menu

if i press f2 as per manufactures manual, then  nothing happens.

when i press fn+f2 i enter elementary os settings, but arrow buttons fail to work here

this happens with and without bootable usb-stick inserted

thanks

Jan

remark: the quality checks applied on the post, did not make it more read able

Comment: see my comments: did use efibootmgr to change order to boot from stick

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the f8 takes you to the boot menu and f11 is the recovery mode which wipes the hard drive. Have you googled your system. Most of the information is in German.

Comment: in elementary 5.1 all buttons were automatically using Fn, i had to press Fn to use them actually as F1-12 buttons. second, it seems that either button was not recognized (i have tried all of them with and withour Fn pressed) or that elementary booted to quick ? i saw such a thread. however, what i did: i have installed efibootmgr and used that to reconfigure boot order. the third trials succeeded: when i ve chosen windows boot manager... then i was able to boot from usb stick and install elementary.

Comment: however, the laptop then  would not boot without stick, would hang in medion flag page, so i did boot with stick and then again with efibootmgr had to change order.
now i can boot without the stick and system seems to work